# Storing linked list in a file, retaining its structure

Tags: java, data-structures, file-handling

I am writing a java program of creating and storing the linked list in a file. So after I create the linked list, I want to store it in a file and close my console,
and again when I read that file I should get same linked list with the links between each nodes retained, but I am unable to perform that. So does anybody has idea about storing a linked list in any file with the links retained for future use.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: you could make use the `Serializable` interface to store the Object itself as a binary representation in a file.

Comment: If you're using the built-in `java.util.LinkedList` then it already implements the `Serializable` interface - you could just use an `ObjectOutputStream` to write it out to file and an `ObjectInputStream` to read it back in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the content in a String and separate the List Items with an "\n". Than you can put the String in a file and read it from file. After reading, you put the content back in the list.